# Surge ability die for legendary items

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, mythic-adventures

Legendary Surge ability for legendary items ends as:

> The legendary surge ability allows the bearer to add the result of a d6 to the appropriate type of roll or check. A mythic bearer can use her surge die type in place of the d6. If she’s bonded to the item, she can increase that die type by one step.

So a 20th level character of 10th mythic tier bonded to the item uses 1d12 increased by one step which means ... 3d6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Probably 2d8

The rules just mention that the die type is increased by one step, but do not provide a rule what dice to use in this situation. So, ultimately, this will the GMs call.

There is however the **Greater Surge (Su)** ability from Mythic Adventures, page 39, which states:

> Your surge is more powerful than most. Treat your tier as if it were 3 higher for the purpose of determining your mythic surge die (maximum 10th tier). When you gain your 10th tier, **your surge die becomes 2d8**.

So, while at 10th tier you normally would use a d12, this ability, which increases the power of your surge at 10th tier instructs you to use 2d8 instead. It might be reasonable to also use that in this case.

This also makes sense from a balance perspective. The amount of numerical increment gained between d6, d8, d10 and d12 on the average result is 1 pip. Between d12 (average 6.5) and 2d8 (9) it is 2.5 pips, somehwat better. 2d6 (7) would be just half a pip, and cannot increase the maximum achievable at all, that is likely too disappointing to warrant consideration. An uneven dice combination of d8+d6 (8) for 1.5 pips gain is most simliar while maintaining an increase of at least 1 pip, but seems unelegant. 3d6 (11, increase of 4.5 pips) or d20 (10.5, increase of 4 pips) both seem too large.